# Limit of $[\ln (3+x^2) - \ln (2+x)]$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$

Tags: limits

I got an answer as $\infty$ but I need more clear explanation.

Please help me!

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. The spirit here is to show a bit of work before people try to give you appropriate advice. What have you tried? Try to be explicit.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that since

$$\log A-\log B= \log \frac{A}B$$

we have

$$\log (3+x^2) - \log (2+x)=\log\left(\frac{3+x^2}{2+x}\right)\to+\infty$$

indeed

$$\frac{3+x^2}{2+x}=x\frac{\frac3{x^2}+1}{\frac1{x}+1}\to +\infty$$

Comment: Thank yo so much!!

Comment: @JooHoLee You are welcome! If you are ok you can accept the answer to set as solved! Bye http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Write
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(\ln(3+x^2)-\ln(2+x))=\ln\left[\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3+x^2}{2+x}\right].
$$

Comment: Appreciate it. THanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You can use *equivalents*, and the properties of log:
$$\ln(3+x^2)-\ln(1+x)=\ln \frac{x^2+3}{x+1}.$$
On the other hand,
$$\frac{x^2+3}{x+1}\sim_\infty \frac{x^2}x=\ln x\enspace\text{so}\quad\ln(3+x^2)-\ln(1+x)\sim_\infty \ln x.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \inf}ln(3+x^2) - ln(2+x)$$ can be symplified as $$\lim_{x \to \inf}ln( \frac{3+x^2}{2+x})$$
So, we can use this as a truth.
$$\lim_{x \to \inf} \frac {1}{x} = 0$$
And we will have
$$\lim_{x \to \inf}ln( \frac{x^2( \frac{3}{x^2}+1)}{x (\frac{2}{x}+1)})$$

As you see, you’ll have $x$ left so the answer is $\inf$